# Помогите найти ошибку в с++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

У меня на форме есть меню:

```
Меню Настройки _ X
```

Хочу пункты `меню _` и `X` передвинуть в правую сторону.
Например:

```
Меню Настройки ................................... ................. _ X
```

Написал код на DELPHI:
Код:

```
ModifyMenu(MainMenu1.Handle, 2, MF_BYPOSITION or MF_RIGHTJUSTIFY, 2, 
           PChar(MainMenu1.Items[2].Caption));
```

Написал код на с++:
Код:

```
ModifyMenu(MainMenu1->Handle, 2, MF_BYPOSITION && MF_RIGHTJUSTIFY, 2, 
           PChar(MainMenu1->Items->Items[2]->Caption));
```

Код в с++ не работает. Что не так. 
Выбивает ошибку следующего вида:

> cannot cast from 'const ansistring' to 'char'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде как минимум ещё одна ошибка - оператор or это не &&. Лучше писать | (палочка, пайп).

```
ModifyMenu(MainMenu1->Handle, 2, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_RIGHTJUSTIFY, 2, 
       MainMenu1->Items->Items[2]->Caption.c_str());
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает.